# Finding a list of file names from a CSV file and then copying them to a directory

Tags: csv, zsh

I have a large set of photos (+5000 in many different folders on a hard drive) and have a .csv file with a select list of 500 photos that we want to copy off the hard drive.

The .CSV has the file names with not extension. All names are unique.

when I run

```
cat selected.csv
```

I get all the files printed. (single column, no header csv file)

When I try to pipe that to a find command, the out put only includes the last line of the .csv.

```
cat selected.csv | xargs -I {} find /photo/harddrive/ -type f -name "{}*"
```

For some reason it's not going through all the lines. Why would that be?

Comment: So after more thinking, a friend and I came up with this.

Answer (score 0):

First we did this:

'while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
echo $line
line=${line%$'\r'}
file=$(find /SOURCE -name "${line}.*" -print)
echo "$file" | tee -a /output.txt
done < "$1"'

This goes through the CSV file pipes it to the find command and prints the path to the matching file.

Then we run this

'cat ~/output.txt | xargs -I {} cp {} ~/OUTPUT'

Answer (score 0):

I tested this script with zsh 5.7.1 and added references for the little details inline:

```
#!/bin/zsh

# -------------
# config

searchFolder="/tmp/test/some"
destinationFolder="/tmp/test/dest"
filterFile="/tmp/test/filter-file"
verbose=true

# end of config
# -------------

cpCommand=""
if [ $verbose = "true" ]; then
    cpCommand="cp -v "
else
    cpCommand="cp "
fi

zmodload zsh/mapfile

# load all lines of file "filter-file" into array $arrayFilterFiles using "mapfile"
arrayFilterFiles=(${(f)mapfile[$filterFile]})

# load paths to any file below folder "$searchFolder" into array "$arrayFileSystem"
# each line of output of "find" will be one item in the array because of subscript flag "(f)"
# see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags
arrayFileSystem=(${(f)"$(find $searchFolder -type f)"})

# search each item of $arrayFileSystem in $arrayFileSystem
for filter in ${arrayFilterFiles}; do 

  # by default in zsh, array index 0 and 1 point to the same item, so start with 1
  # see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts
  for (( fsIndex = 1; $fsIndex <= ${#arrayFileSystem[@]}; fsIndex++ )) do 

    # the modifier ":t" (tail) returns the string after last "/", like 'basename' command
    # see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers
    # the parameter-expansion "%" removes the smallest matching pattern from end of variable, i.e. removes .jpg
    # see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion
    if [ "${${${arrayFileSystem[$fsIndex]}:t}%.*}" = "$filter" ]; then 

      # finding
      echo "${cpCommand} ${arrayFileSystem[$fsIndex]} ${destinationFolder}"
    fi
  done
done
```

Content of test filter file:

```
% cat filter-file 
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

A test folder structure with some jpg files:

```
% find some -type f | sort
some/folder/with/files/file1.jpg
some/folder/with/files/file2.jpg
some/folder/with/other/stuff/file3.jpg
some/other/folder/with/more/data/file4.jpg
some/other/folder/with/more/data/file42.jpg
some/other/folder/with/more/data/file5.jpg
```

The script finds all files in the folder structure, which are in the filter file

```
% ./script.zsh    
cp -v /tmp/test/some/folder/with/files/file1.jpg /tmp/test/dest
cp -v /tmp/test/some/folder/with/files/file2.jpg /tmp/test/dest
cp -v /tmp/test/some/folder/with/other/stuff/file3.jpg /tmp/test/dest
cp -v /tmp/test/some/other/folder/with/more/data/file4.jpg /tmp/test/dest
```

Add parameters to the script for the variables in the config part, if you like